# PHP - Echo doesn't print some values

Tags: php, parsing

i've a strange problem in PHP. 
I'm doing a parsing of a webpage, and i get the correct values i'm looking for. The problem is that if i want to print them, all together into an "echo", it prints only certain values, while the others are not printed. I make you an example, this is NOT my real code because i can't past here my source (it's to long and i can make a shorter example).

```
<?php
 $variable1 = function_to_get_this_variable;
 $variable2 = function_to_get_this_variable;
 $variable3 = function_to_get_this_variable;
 $variable4 = function_to_get_this_variable;
 $variable5 = function_to_get_this_variable;
 $variable6 = function_to_get_this_variable;
```

Now, if i print each value individually (i.e. through echo $variable1;), i get the value i'm looking for. But if try to print them together, through

```
echo("This is the variable 1: " . $variable1 . " This is the variable 2: " . $variable2 . " This is the variable 3 :" . $variable3 . " This is the variable 4: " . $variable4 . " This is the variable 5: " . $variable5 . " This is the variable 6: " . $variable6);
```

It prints only variables until variables 4, then it doesn't print nothing. If i leave only

```
echo(" This is the variable 5: " . $variable5 . " This is the variable 6: " . $variable6);
```

It prints only the variable 5. And again, if leave only

```
echo(" This is the variable 6: " . $variable6);
```

It prints the sixth correctly.

Which can be the problem? Also, i remember you that i'm doing a parsing of a webpage (if it can be useful). 
Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use an array for storing...?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. Just because it ended up being a fairly easy solution does not mean it warrants a downvote. You've got a +1 for me for a well-written question with a good amount of code examples and original research.

Comment: @ThomasKelley agreed, well said!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply missing speech marks (and you might as well drop the `()`, `echo` is a language construct.).

Try this:

```
echo "This is the variable 1: " 
. $variable1 . " This is the variable 2: " 
. $variable2 . " This is the variable 3: "
. $variable3 . " This is the variable 4: " 
. $variable4 . " This is the variable 5: " 
. $variable5 . " This is the variable 6: " 
. $variable6 ;
```

Based on @mario's advice, you would be easier off using interpolation, which means inside **double quotes** the $variable will be parsed. Use `{}` to surround the $variable if the need arises.

Comment: Correct - I would recommend that OP uses syntax highlighting in the future to avoid mistakes like this.

Comment: @RobFarr true, one look at the question and the syntax makes it blindingly obvious. Also good to break up the lines to be able to see what is going on!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you recommend concatenation instead of interpolation? I mean OP seems confused enough about the syntax. Why eschew the simpler feature that's the raison d'être for scripting languages?

Comment: @mario not really, was just quicker and less to change. Will edit it in now, thanks!

Comment: @mario dont forget the next question people normally ask after discovering interpolation, why isnt this working. `$a ='Hello $username'`

Comment: @InGodITrust True, that's super common for newcomers. Mostly because of editors without syntax highlighting and IDE avoidance though I presume.

Comment: @mario thats why these comments are so good, the OP can see what peolpe discuss and learn from the comments too!

Comment: Thanks all for all the replies, i've tried everything but this strange problem persists. I prints each value correctly, but if i try to print all together it doesn't print the last 2 variables. Anyone knows why it happens and how to solve it? Thanks again

Comment: @InGodITrust solved right now. I've "fixed" the code by using double quote and by putting variables directly into it, then i've seen that i left a </td> tag while i parsed the page, this "stopped the echo", and it didn't print anything else. Sorry everyone, it was an idiot problem. Anyway, i learned how to use correctly the echo quotes. 
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

First of all... If you're using double-quotes `"` you can do just this:

```
echo "This is the variable 1: $variable1 
      This is the variable 2: $variable2 
      This is the variable 3: $variable3 
      This is the variable 4: $variable4 
      This is the variable 5: $variable5 
      This is the variable 6: $variable6";
```

In case you want to use special char next to var or array you can do this:

```
echo "This is the variable 1: {$variable1} 
      This is the variable 2: {$variable2} 
      This is the variable 3: {$variable3} 
      This is the variable 4: {$variable4} 
      This is the variable 5: {$variable5} 
      This is the variable 6: {$variable6}";
```

Using `"` is slower than `'` because interpreter looking for variables inside `""` echo. Single quote solution looks like one of answers here:

```
echo 'This is the variable 1: '
     . $variable1 . ' This is the variable 2: ' 
     . $variable2 . ' This is the variable 3: '
     . $variable3 . ' This is the variable 4: ' 
     . $variable4 . ' This is the variable 5: ' 
     . $variable5 . ' This is the variable 6: '
     . $variable6 ;
```

Almost forgot about something... Not many people use it and it's much more readable than above example:

```
echo 'This is the variable 1: '.$variable1,
     'This is the variable 2: '.$variable2,
     'This is the variable 3: '.$variable3,
     'This is the variable 4: '.$variable4,
     'This is the variable 5: '.$variable5,
     'This is the variable 6: '.$variable6;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Tried right now but i don't know why, the problem persists. Variables are stored correctly, but are not printed. It doesn't print also the text before variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think your statement is malformed...

```
echo("This is the variable 1: " . $variable1 . " This is the variable 2: " . $variable2 . " This is the variable 3 : . $variable3 . " This is the variable 4: " . $variable4 . " This is the variable 5: " . $variable5 . " This is the variable 6: " . $variable6);
```

Should be:

```
echo("This is the variable 1: " . $variable1 . " This is the variable 2: " . $variable2 . " This is the variable 3 " . $variable3 . " This is the variable 4: " . $variable4 . " This is the variable 5: " . $variable5 . " This is the variable 6: " . $variable6);
```

You may also want to take advantage of PHP's double-quote variable expansion. I find it helps in simple cases like this...

```
echo("This is the variable 1: $variable1 This is the variable 2: $variable2 This is the variable 3: $variable3 This is the variable 4: $variable4 This is the variable 5: $variable5 This is the variable 6: $variable6");
```

Comment: I've written it wrongly, now i've edited it. I've tried right now double quotes, but the problem persists..

Answer (score 0):

Try using *sprintf* instead

```
$VarToPrint = sprintf("This is the variable 1: %s This is the variable 2: %s This is the variable 3: %s This is the variable 4: %s This is the variable 5: %s This is the variable 6: %s", $variable1, $variable2, $variable3, $variable4, $variable5, $variable6);
```

Next you just *echo $VarToPrint;*

Comment: `printf` sounds better if don't want to do anything else with prepared string.